# jQuery find returns empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am doing ajax POST and when it succeded I would like to replace current div with div from succeded ajax:

```
var dom;
var target;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1/participants",   
    data: "action=addparticipant&userid=1",
    success: function (html) {

        dom = $.parseHTML(html);
        target = $(dom).find("#listParticipants").val();

        $('#listParticipants').html(target);                
    }
});
```

but it seems that `target` is empty...

and when I debug using firebug, than `dom` is:

```
[<TextNode textContent="\n\n">, <TextNode textContent="\n\n">,
div#listParticipants, <TextNode textContent="\n \n \n">,
<TextNode textContent="\n\n">, <TextNode textContent="\n\n">]
```

Could anyone help me solve this problem?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [$.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), not $.find

```
target = $(dom).filter("#listParticipants").html()
```

And as Juan pointed out, you want the innerHTML, not the value.

The reason you need to use filter is your console is showing an array of nodes and not a single DOM element. That means that you need to filter that set.

Comment: Out of curiousity can you please explain why filter is better than find? It seems to be doing the same thing here.

Comment: @Spokey Because `dom` is not an element, but an array of them.

Comment: @JuanMendes `.find` only look for descendant. You can see that all his element are in the root of the array. This is the good answer.

Comment: Edited just so I can upvote it now that I see why the OP should use filter

Answer (score 2):

The `$().val()` method is for input fields. See http://api.jquery.com/val/

Also as pointed out by epascarello https://stackoverflow.com/a/25142313/227299, you have a set of nodes, so you need to `$.filter`, not `$.find`

If you want the `innerHTML`, use `$(dom).filter("#listParticipants").html()`

Comment: Not the downvoter, but probably because this will not work. Same reason explained on epascarello's answer.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Thanks, I hadn't realized that the HTML in question didn't have a root node

Comment: it is not working in my case. `target` was still empty. epascarello`s solution works :)

Comment: @Hladeo Please describe in detail what you mean by it is not working. What is happening? Errors?